# Reciving a xml string from C# program unable to parse with ET.fromstring in Python 3.5

Tags: c#, python

I have a C# program that sends an XML string as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="no"?>
<ScoreList>
  <Player UserName="Player1" Score="10" />
  <Player UserName="Player2" Score="20" />
</ScoreList>
```

But when I receive it in my Python program it looks like this

```
   b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="no"?>
   \r\n<ScoreList>\r\n  
   <Player UserName="Player1" Score="10" />
   \r\n  <Player UserName="Player2" Score="20" />
   \r\n</ScoreList>'
```

I'm sending it to a server with this code C#

```
Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(doc);
        netStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
```

And receiving with this code on the Python(Version 3.5) end

```
self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
```

Then when I try to parse it using this code

```
tree = ET.fromstring(self.data)
```

I get the error:

```
 File "<string>", line None
 xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, 
 column 1
```

Any advice on where I'm going wrong or what I could try to fix this.

Comment: Don't know much about Python but it seems you are trying to parse XML by string function. I believe there must be some XML parsing functions https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Hemant Sakta I'm using a String function because the xml is turned into string on the c# side and then I want to change it back to xml on the python side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you are calling `str` on a `bytes` instance somewhere in your code.

Consider this xml fragment:

```
>>> x = '<foo>Hello world</foo>'
```

If it is being sent across the network it will must be encoded as bytes.

```
>>> bs = x.encode('utf-8')
>>> bs
b'<foo>Hello world</foo>'
```

ElementTree will accept the UTF-8 encoded bytes as is, or you can decode them before passing them to ElementTree:

```
>>> decoded = bs.decode('utf-8')
>>> decoded
'<foo>Hello world</foo>'
```

However if you call `str` on the bytes, you'll get the [*repr*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) of the bytes, which will include the leading `b`:

```
>>> stringified = str(bs)
>>> stringified
"b'<foo>Hello world</foo>'"
```

ElementTree will not accept this input:

```
>>> ET.fromstring(stringified)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 1
```

To fix this, you need to look at how `self.data` is being constructed.  Make sure that you are calling `decode()` on the bytes that you receive, rather than `str()`.

Comment: Thank You. My issue was the way I had written the decode.